# don't wake up, ubuntu 20.04.4 and updated to 20.10

Tags: suspend

hp laptop,don't wake up after sleep!

```
(base) nal@nal-hp:~$ uname -r
5.13.0-35-generic
(base) nal@nal-hp:~$ sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
update-manager-core is already the newest version (1:21.10.5).
update-manager-core set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Please clarify your OS & release.  Ubuntu 20.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/07/25/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-end-of-life-reached-on-july-22-2021/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades   Note: [Ubuntu release upgrader tool](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader) won't let you upgrade to an EOL release; and 20.10 used the now EOL 5.8 kernel.

Comment: Please check your currently off-topic question & most likely correct your incorrect details.  The package in your paste is `update-manager-core | 1:21.10.5     | impish-updates  | all` which you'll note is *impish*, 20.10 you mention was *groovy* - so your 20.10 is almost certainly an error (*impish* = 21.10 or the 2021-October release that is *supported* and thus on-topic here).